# Reducing/merging vector features after QGIS Vectorize?

Tags: qgis, vector

i have a high res raster layer. Each pixel has an attribute value between 0 - 10000. I would like to vectorize the layer and finally get a geojson object. But atm i get for each pixel an own vector object and finally a huge geojson file. I think it's because of the different values.

How can I reduce the number of generated vector elements?

Comment: How detailed do you need the output? You could reclassify your raster by ranges, perhaps.

Comment: What geometry type are you after? (point, line or polygon) You could try tiling the image, you'd still get the same number of vectors but in multiple files rather than one big one. Why are you vectorizing the image? What benefit do vectors have that you can't use the raster instead? Why GEOJSON? A shapefile, being binary, would be much smaller.